# Matching one of several characters at the last position in a HTML input's value

Tags: html, regex

## Problem:

I have the following code as part of a form.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0|3|7]+$" title="Value must end in either 0, 3 or 7" required>
```

When attempting to submit the form, it should only submit correctly if the value of the input ends in `0`, `3`, or `7`.

Currently, it is not working as expected and will only match the following values:

- `0`
- `3`
- `7`

If there is any other character in the input, it will not match.

## Examples/demos:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9of0w2cm/

Demo of regex working: https://regexr.com/3sii4

Examples that should match:

- `1.0`
- `1.3`
- `7.3`
- `8.7`

Examples that should not match:

- `1.1`
- `1.5`
- `7.9`
- `8.2`

What is the issue causing the regex to not match expected results?

Comment: You need `pattern=".*[037]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-pattern-attribute) is already anchored by default so `[0|3|7]+$` would match 037 or a pipe from the start until the end of the line.

You might use:

[`(?:[0-9]\.)*[037]`](https://regex101.com/r/y3ddbP/1/)

**Explanation**

- `(?:[0-9]\.)*` Repeat in a non capturing group a digit followed by a dot zero or more times.
- `[037]` Match 0, 3 or 7 using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

To match one or more digits before the dot and one or more digits after the dot you might use [`[0-9]+\.[0-9]*[037]`](https://regex101.com/r/b046b2/1).

To match one digit, a dot and one digit you  might use [`[0-9]\.[037]`](https://regex101.com/r/cuvihs/1)

```html
<form id="" name="">
  <input type="text" pattern="(?:[0-9]\.)*[037]" title="Value must end in either 0, 3 or 7" required>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I think your answer has an error which is in there `[0-9]\.)*` this regex doesn't match bigger number than 9, the repeated number is with a dot which is like this `1.2.3` i think expected value is `12.3` not `1.2.3`, so if you want just number before the end value i suggest `\d*\.[037]` and if you want to use any other characters before the end value so i suggest `.*\.[037]`.

Comment: @Azhy My answer is based on the example data which uses digits and dots. `.*\.[037]` would also match but the dot matches any character. In case of not matching a repeated group with a dot but just 1 time a dot with multiple digits before and after the OP could use [`[0-9]+\.[0-9]*[037]`](https://regex101.com/r/b046b2/1) or with a single digit after [`[0-9]+\.[037]`](https://regex101.com/r/oSYUuE/1/). Your suggesion [`\d*\.[037]`](https://regex101.com/r/hKQWca/1) also matches a leading dot like `.7`.